# IIS URL Redirecting to another server for specific subfolder

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-farm

I am quite new to IIS Web Farms and url rewriting/redirecting.I need my IIS server to redirect an HTTP request to another server if it has some specific subfolder in the url.

I have a domain with domain name;  **example.com** , and it is bound to a Web Application that is running on a machine with IP address **111.111.111.111** .I also have another web application running on a machine with IP address **222.222.222.222**. So,what i need is when server receives an HTTP request with a URL that contains a subdirectory named **NewApp**  it shall redirect to the IP address **222.222.222.222**.

For example;

If request url is something like **example.com/OldApp** or **example.com**  then request shall be served by the web application running on machine with IP address  111.111.111.111

if request url starts with **example.com/NewApi** then request shall be served by the web application running on machine with IP address  222.222.222.222

How can i achieve this by using url rewrite module of IIS?

Comment: You can search about redirecting subdomains... maybe these links help: https://forums.iis.net/t/1216172.aspx and https://www.brainarama.com/thought/8af37050-9051-11e7-8efa-871c7c192f33/IIS-7-URL-Rewrite-subdomains-and-host-headers

Comment: Sadly, I could not make it work with IIS. I have solved this problem by creating subdomains.

Comment: It is recommended you put your solution as the answer, so other users with same problem can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using subdirectory, I created subdomain as ;  newApi.example.com and set DNS records for it. I didn't go with reverse proxy solution.